# Using openssh public key (ecdsa-sha2-nistp256) with Java Security

Tags: java, openssh, jce, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

Is there a Java library/example to read an openssh format ecdsa public key to a JCE `PublicKey` in Java? I want to use EC for [JWT](https://jwt.io) .

The format I'm trying to read is as per authorized_keys, or Github API (e.g. https://api.github.com/users/davidcarboni/keys):  `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBK8hPtB72/sfYgNw1WTska2DNOJFx+QhUxuV6OLINSD2ty+6gxcM8yZrvMqWdMePGRb2cGh8L/0bGOk+64IQ/pM=`

I've found this answer, which is fine for RSA and DSS:
[Using public key from authorized_keys with Java security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531506/using-public-key-from-authorized-keys-with-java-security), and this discussion of the openssh format for ECDSA: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129910/ecdsa-why-do-ssh-keygen-and-java-generated-public-keys-have-different-sizes

However I'm getting lost trying to adapt the RSS/DSA code for ECDSA - I'm not sure how to set up an [`ECPublicKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECPublicKeySpec.html). It needs `ECPoint`, `EllipticCurve`, `ECParameterSpec`, `ECField`. The openssh format only contains two integers, which makes sense for `ECPoint`, but I don't know how to set up the rest.

I've been poking around a bunch of libraries, including [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj), [ssh-tools](https://www.sshtools.com/en/products/opensource/) and good old [Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). The closest I have is:

`com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair load = com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(jsch, null, bytes[openSshKey]);`

Which loads the key fine, but doesn't get me to a JCE `PublicKey` - just a `byte[] getPublicKeyBlob()` method.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I've made some progress in setting up `ECPublicKeySpec` by using [`com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.ECKey`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/2.21/com/nimbusds/jose/jwk/ECKey.Curve.html). This provides a `ECKey.Curve.P_256.toECParameterSpec()` call, which sorts out most of the mystery parameters. That just leaves the [`ECPoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECPoint.html), so it's looking more likely the RSA/DSA example could be adapted.

Comment: So, well, interesting. I'm adapting the RSA/DSA example and am getting the values "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256", "nistp256" and then just one BigInt (rather than two). I'm wondering if that's the "public part" only given it's a public key? I guess it's time to read [RFC 5656, section 3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5656#section-3.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, here's the code I've gone with. It's nearly-pure JCE, with a sprinkling of Bouncycastle inside helper methods (this updates the example code in [Using public key from authorized_keys with Java security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531506/using-public-key-from-authorized-keys-with-java-security)):

```
...
        } else if (type.startsWith("ecdsa-sha2-") &&
                (type.endsWith("nistp256") || type.endsWith("nistp384") || type.endsWith("nistp521"))) {
            // Based on RFC 5656, section 3.1 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5656#section-3.1)
            String identifier = decodeType();
            BigInteger q = decodeBigInt();
            ECPoint ecPoint = getECPoint(q, identifier);
            ECParameterSpec ecParameterSpec = getECParameterSpec(identifier);
            ECPublicKeySpec spec = new ECPublicKeySpec(ecPoint, ecParameterSpec);
            return KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePublic(spec);
        } ...

/**
 * Provides a means to get from a parsed Q value to the X and Y point values.
 * that can be used to create and ECPoint compatible with ECPublicKeySpec.
 *
 * @param q          According to RFC 5656:
 *                   "Q is the public key encoded from an elliptic curve point into an octet string"
 * @param identifier According to RFC 5656:
 *                   "The string [identifier] is the identifier of the elliptic curve domain parameters."
 * @return An ECPoint suitable for creating a JCE ECPublicKeySpec.
 */
ECPoint getECPoint(BigInteger q, String identifier) {
    String name = identifier.replace("nist", "sec") + "r1";
    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(name);
    org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint point = ecSpec.getCurve().decodePoint(q.toByteArray());
    BigInteger x = point.getAffineXCoord().toBigInteger();
    BigInteger y = point.getAffineYCoord().toBigInteger();
    System.out.println("BC x = " + x);
    System.out.println("BC y = " + y);
    return new ECPoint(x, y);
}

/**
 * Gets the curve parameters for the given key type identifier.
 *
 * @param identifier According to RFC 5656:
 *                   "The string [identifier] is the identifier of the elliptic curve domain parameters."
 * @return An ECParameterSpec suitable for creating a JCE ECPublicKeySpec.
 */
ECParameterSpec getECParameterSpec(String identifier) {
    try {
        // http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=362269#SupportedCurves(ECDSAandECGOST)-NIST(aliasesforSECcurves)
        String name = identifier.replace("nist", "sec") + "r1";
        AlgorithmParameters parameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC");
        parameters.init(new ECGenParameterSpec(name));
        return parameters.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec.class);
    } catch (InvalidParameterSpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to get parameter spec for identifier " + identifier, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there anyway I could convince you to share your project on github? I'm worried that my seemingly identical question will be flagged as a repeat of yours and have a limited understanding of cryptography. Thanks - Chris

Comment: Happily that code is visible on Github, at least for now: https://github.com/rosgovuk/discharges-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/gov/ros/discharges/security/OpenSshPublicKey.java I'll take a backup just in case, feel free to ask if it does disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to do this using Bouncycastle (but would like to find a JCE way).

Adapting the code from [Using public key from authorized_keys with Java security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531506/using-public-key-from-authorized-keys-with-java-security), and refering to [RFC 5656, section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#section-3.1), the following block added to `decodePublicKey` will parse the single BigInt value Q, which is "the public key encoded from an elliptic curve point":

```
if (type.startsWith("ecdsa-sha2-") &&
            (type.endsWith("nistp256") || type.endsWith("nistp384") || type.endsWith("nistp521"))) {

        // Based on RFC 5656, section 3.1 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#section-3.1)

        // The string [identifier] is the identifier of the elliptic curve
        // domain parameters.  The format of this string is specified in
        // Section 6.1 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#section-6.1).
        // Information on the REQUIRED and RECOMMENDED sets of
        // elliptic curve domain parameters for use with this algorithm can be
        // found in Section 10 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#section-10).
        String identifier = decodeType();
        if (!type.endsWith(identifier)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid identifier " + identifier + " for key type " + type + ".");
        }

        // Q is the public key encoded from an elliptic curve point into an
        // octet string as defined in Section 2.3.3 of [SEC1];
        // (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#ref-SEC1)
        // point compression MAY be used.
        BigInteger q = decodeBigInt();

        ECPublicKey keyBC = getKeyBC(q, identifier);
        return keyBC;
    }
```

The solution I've found for getting from Q to an `ECPublicKey` is the following, using the Bouncycastle API (credit to [Generate ECPublicKey from ECPrivateKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639620/generate-ecpublickey-from-ecprivatekey) for providing the starting point):

```
ECPublicKey getKeyBC(BigInteger q, String identifier) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639620/generate-ecpublickey-from-ecprivatekey
    try {
        // This only works with the Bouncycastle library:
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        // http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=362269#SupportedCurves(ECDSAandECGOST)-NIST(aliasesforSECcurves)
        String name = identifier.replace("nist", "sec") + "r1";
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
        ECNamedCurveParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(name);
        ECPoint point = ecSpec.getCurve().decodePoint(q.toByteArray());
        ECPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(point, ecSpec);
        ECPublicKey publicKey = (ECPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(pubSpec);
        return publicKey;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

That gets you from an openssh format elliptic curve public key (`ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b [256|384|521]`) to a JCE `ECPublicKey`.

Comment: I've posted a new question about whether there's a JCE way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829426/can-i-create-a-jca-ecpublickey-from-a-q-value-from-an-openssh-public-key-and-ecp