# Can I create a JCE ECPublicKey from a Q value from an openssh public key and ECParameterSpec

Tags: java, openssh, jce, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

I'm reading openssh format elliptic curve public keys ([RFC 5656, section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#section-3.1)) and would like to get from a BigInteger Q value to an `ECPublicKey` instance using JCE (rather than say BouncyCastle). I want to do this to verify [JWT](https://jwt.io) signatures.

e.g. https://api.github.com/users/davidcarboni/keys:

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBK8hPtB72/sfYgNw1WTska2DNOJFx+QhUxuV6OLINSD2ty+6gxcM8yZrvMqWdMePGRb2cGh8L/0bGOk+64IQ/pM=
```

It looks like I can use `ECPublicKeySpec`. This takes two parameters. An `ECPoint` and an `ECParameterSpec`. I'm able to get the parameter spec using the following JCE code (and the openssh identifier from the key data, say "nistp256"):

```
ECParameterSpec getECParameterSpec(String identifier) {
    try {
        AlgorithmParameters parameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC");
        String name = identifier.replace("nist", "sec") + "r1";
        parameters.init(new ECGenParameterSpec(name));
        return parameters.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec.class);
    } catch (InvalidParameterSpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to get parameter spec for identifier " + identifier, e);
    }
}
```

I've successfully parsed the Q value from the key data. RFC 5656 tells me that "Q is the public key encoded from an elliptic curve point into an octet string") however the constructor of JCE's `ECPoint` class takes two parameters, X and Y.

Can I get to X and Y from Q, or do I need to take a different approach?

(NB I quite rightly don't have access to the private key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base64 portion of your input has the equivalent hex of

```
00 00 00 13 65 63 64 73 61 2D 73 68 61 32 2D 6E 
69 73 74 70 32 35 36 00 00 00 08 6E 69 73 74 70 
32 35 36 00 00 00 41 04 AF 21 3E D0 7B DB FB 1F 
62 03 70 D5 64 EC 91 AD 83 34 E2 45 C7 E4 21 53 
1B 95 E8 E2 C8 35 20 F6 B7 2F BA 83 17 0C F3 26 
6B BC CA 96 74 C7 8F 19 16 F6 70 68 7C 2F FD 1B 
18 E9 3E EB 82 10 FE 93
```

65 63 64 jumped out to me as "ecd" (sure enough, "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256").

So the blob looks to be

- Big Endian length of a string/payload (19)
- The string "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256"
- Big Endian length of a string/payload (8)
- The string "nistp256"
- Big Endian length of a payload (0x41 == 65)
- The encoded ECPoint Q (`04 AF 21 ... 10 FE 93`)

The encoded ECPoint starts with `04` indicating it is an uncompressed point (the most common encoding).  The `04` encoding rules (from http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf, 2.3.5, step 3) say that the remaining payload is X and Y, each left-padded with zeros to the encoding size of the curve field.

So your ECPoint looks like

```
04
Qx:
AF 21 3E D0 7B DB FB 1F 62 03 70 D5 64 EC 91 AD
83 34 E2 45 C7 E4 21 53 1B 95 E8 E2 C8 35 20 F6
Qy:
B7 2F BA 83 17 0C F3 26 6B BC CA 96 74 C7 8F 19
16 F6 70 68 7C 2F FD 1B 18 E9 3E EB 82 10 FE 93
```

In C# you'd need to a) reverse the bytes of each of Qx and Qy (because the .NET BigInteger expects Little Endian, and these are Big Endian) and b) put a padding 0x00 byte as more significant than the 0xAF and 0xB7 bytes, since they have their high bits set (and would be interpreted as negative numbers).  Don't know if Java has either of those quirks.

Comment: Nice, OK, so if I'm understanding correctly, Q is a string of bytes that starts with a byte identifying the format, followed by (in the case of 04/uncompressed) two sets of bytes of equal length which represent BigIntegers X and Y?

Comment: @DavidCarboni yep, you got it.

Comment: Success! For the benefit of Googlers, I split the byte array of Q into the first byte ("04") and two sections of equal length (32 bytes each in my case) as you explained, and was then able to use standard JCE `java.security.spec.ECPoint point = new java.security.spec.ECPoint(x,y);` where x and y are `BigInteger` values created with those two sections.

Comment: To complete the story, from there, `new java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec(point, curveSpec)` (where `curveSpec` was created using the code in the question) and good old `KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePublic(spec)` got me to a `PublicKey`. To prove this was the correct key, I created a keypair using `ssh-keygen`, signed a JWT with the private key (with help from Bouncycastle's `PEMParser`) and decoded the public key with both the Bouncycastle Q approach and the JCE X/Y approach. I was able to verify the signature using both of those public key instances.

Comment: Also worth noting that the code of `ECCurve#decodePoint(byte[])` (https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/ECCurve.html#decodePoint(byte[])) implements the different encodings (other than 04) so it's possible to use `ECPoint p = new ECPoint(point.getAffineXCoord().toBigInteger(), point.getAffineYCoord().toBigInteger());` to get ta JCE ECPoint, albeit using the BC helper class.

Comment: I've posted the completed code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808132/using-openssh-public-key-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-with-java-security/44907432#44907432